# Angular multi-select dropdown and lodash countby

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash, html-select

I am kinda drawing a blank on this one facet, and I can't seem to quite figure it out.

So I have a simple HTML select => option element which is populated from the back-end (not really relevant tho)

My question is this:

Let's say I have a pre-made object such as this:

```
{
    keyName1: 450,
    keyName2: 800,
    keyName3: 300
}
```

What I want to do is to check if the key name matches a name of an option value in my multi-select dropdown (the values come from an array, using 'ng-repeat' on the option), and if the option value matches the key, add the number value to some sort of increment variable, so I can display the total number of 'keyNames' found.

For example - if a user selects 'keyName1' the incrementer value will total 450. If a user selects 'keyName1' and 'keyName2' the incrementer value will total 1,250.

I am lost on how to accomplish this - right now it is reading only the very first item in the dropdown.

Here is the code doing that:

```
_.forEach($scope.widget.instance.settings.serviceContractTypes, function (type) {
     // if item in array matches what is selected in multi-select option
     if(type === $('#contractType:selected').text().trim()) {
        // do stuff
     }
});
```

Hope this all made sense, and thanks very much for any direction you might offer...

(does not have to utilize lodash, I'm just used to using it)

Comment: Re: "right now it is reading only the very first item in the dropdown." - can you share the code which is doing that?

Comment: @anandsun - oops, sorry - added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's :selected selector only works for HTML options:
"The :selected selector works for  elements. It does not work for checkboxes or radio inputs; use :checked for them."
 (https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

You say "I have a simple HTML select => option element which is populated from the back-end (not really relevant tho)"

This could be relevant. By default, an HTML option tag does not support multiple selections; it has to explicitly be created as a select multiple in order to support that. Can you share the HTML code for the option to make it clear whether that's a problem or this is a red herring?

Also, can you echo $scope.widget.instance.settings.serviceContractTypes and share to make sure it's actually matching what's available in the text of the options?

ADDENDUM - Wait, I think I figured it out!

The $('#contractType:selected') selects all the selected options in #contractType and concatenates them. Then $('#contractType:selected').text().trim() trims this down to the first word, which is just the first selected option. You should do something like $('#contractType:selected').text().split(" ") and then check if each type is in the resulting list.

Comment: The multi-select for the option is an Angular service which was created as part of my company's app that we work on - I could share that code, but it's quite large - I can tell you that it works, since we use it across multiple areas of our app.

That isn't really the issue I am having - I am just wanting to check if the selected option(s) match a key in an object, and if so, add that key's value (a number) to an incrementer, to be displayed on a page.

Comment: And and as far as "can you echo $scope.widget.instance.settings.serviceContractTypes" it is just an object like I posted above - and in the option dropdowns, every key name from said object is an option value, which can be selected (one, or multiple) if that helps...

EDIT: jQuery does not need to be used either, I was just trying to figure out how to get this done, that's all

Comment: Based on the information you shared, I don't see why your code shouldn't work, unless the body of the if statement is doing something you don't want, like explicitly setting the sum value instead of accumulating it. It is weird that you're running into issues.

Comment: Right, that's what I was thinking too - but it is only getting the value for the first option value (first keyName), and will not accumulate any other options selected (or even view them as being selected)...

Comment: @Lushmoney Take another look - I had an idea?

Comment: oooooooh that's a great idea!! I am going to try that as soon as I get back to my desk, and let you know...

Comment: Nah, unfortunately no go - it works only when 1 option value is selected; when another one is selected, it breaks down...

Nice thinking tho.

Comment: What exact code did you use? I think the main problem is you're using === to compare a single value to the entire list.

Comment: all good, I figured it out. It was hard to convey all the issues, since there were so many moving parts to my app. But generally, your answer would have been correct were it not for certain services / directives in the app I work on, contributing to different problems.

Will mark your answer as correct - thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150109/discussion-between-anandsun-and-lushmoney).